# Converting an older 10/2 dedicated circuit to a plug in for an EV

Tags: garage

I have a 1991 house that has a 30 amp (double breaker/attached to each other) 240 volt dedicated circuit that originally was hard wired to the water heater before the water heater was removed.
I would like to use this circuit to charge an EV.
Under newer code rules, am I allowed to just attach a three slot 10/30 dryer-type outlet to the two wire/plus ground existing wire and use as is to plug in my EV charging cable?
If converting the existing hard wire to an outlet is not allowed, could I use the existing wire and box and legally hard wire a 10/30 EV cable adaptor (plug end chopped off) into that box and plug my EV cable into the adaptor?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "chop cords". You can't use the old 3-wire dryer receptacle (they're dangerous and not allowed for this use anyway, only grandfathered for existing dryer installations). You can't use a 4-wire dryer receptacle (you don't have neutral). You have the following options:

- Properly hard-wire the EVSE.

This means either running the 10/2 *into* terminals inside the EVSE, or installing a junction box to connect the 10/2 to additional cable (or wires in conduit) which then connects to the EVSE.

- Install the appropriate receptacle on the end of the 10/2 - a NEMA 6-30.

Note that there are two different types - plain 6-30 (two straight pins for the hots plus a small ground) and L6-30 (twist lock, 3 curved pins). You need to install a receptacle and a matching cord/plug.

Hardwiring is preferable for two reasons:

- More secure/one less point of failure. Why have a plug/receptacle that never gets unplugged? Which is why I also recommend hardwiring dishwashers, disposals and ovens.
- GFCI - EVSE provides GFCI protection and automatic reset. But if you install a receptacle, *which could potentially be used for other things besides electric vehicle charging*, the latest NEC requires GFCI protection. And unlike a $15 120V 15A duplex GFCI receptacle, for a 30A EVSE circuit you will need a 30A double-breaker GFCI, which is typically in the $100 range, *if it is even available for your panel*.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> am I allowed to just attach a three slot 10/30 dryer-type outlet

Absolutely not. That particular socket was banned for non-dryer use in 1966 (pre-moonshot) and banned for dryers in 1996.  Stores should be ashamed of themselves for still even stocking the socket, it should be a special order. If your dryer is connected that way, be aware there is a shock hazard, since the dryer has no ground, and is attaching the chassis to neutral.  This kills several people a year.  That's why it was banned in 1996.  It *should* be an easy upgrade to NEMA 14-30.

For EV use, where you need 2 hots and a **ground**, the correct socket is in the very next bin at the store - it is **NEMA 6-30 type**.  If you want to connect your 10/2 cable to a socket, **you must use a 6-30 - no alternative**.

[image]

*"But that's not fair! My EV manufacturer doesn't sell a NEMA 6-30 dongle, but they do sell a NEMA 10-30 dongle! How can this be?"*

Well, they shouldn't do that.  But we can handle it.

**The ideal way to solve this problem is to acquire a *permanent, wall-mount* EVSE such as a Grizzl-E, LCS-30, Juicebox or Tesla Wall Connector, that is hard-wired. This bypasses the plug/socket issue altogether**.

**Most wall-mount EVSEs allow hard-wiring. Check the instructions**.

The portable unit that comes free with the EV is a **travel EVSE** intended to live in your trunk for opportunity charging *"on the road"*. As such, they supply the two plugs you're most likely to find *on the road*: The NEMA 5-15 found everywhere, and the NEMA 14-50 found at RV parks and friends with RVs. This was never intended for at-home daily charging.

However, some EV manufacturers sell NEMA 14-30 and 10-30 dongles (but not 6-30) for these travel units, and I might guess that's the issue here.   In that case, you must purchase the NEMA 10-30 dongle, and then, make a cheater cord to take it to 6-30.  This is silly but necessary because of their policies.

The cheater cord will consist of a NEMA 10-30R socket, mounted in any practical way, and then a NEMA 6-30 plug.  This will then plug into the NEMA 6-30 outlet you legally installed.

[image]

"On those travel charger dongles, can't I just lop off the plug and change it? That'll save me the cost of a socket and aluminum junction box."

**Absolutely NOT**. On travel dongles, the plug itself contains a microchip.  **The microchip tells the car the ampacity of the socket**. This is not your father's battery charger :) *[The charger is on board the car](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)* and the EVSE's job is simply to be a GFCI and tell the car how many amps it can pull. The plug microchip also has a temperature sensor to back off charge rate if the socket gets hot, which happens *a lot*.  This is a UL requirement. If you lop off the plug, that's destroyed and it won't charge anymore (won't know what the amps are).

That is why *it's essential* that any cheater cords use **the same amps** on both ends.  For instance the car comes with a 14-50 dongle. If a half-wit made an adapter to a 6-***30*** socket, the car would think it was on a 50A socket. See how that wouldn't end well?