# Does an EV charging circuit call for GFCI or AFCI protection?

Tags: electrical

What is common or recommended for mobile EV charger, GFCI in main panel or AFCI, or both?

I read that the mobile charger already has GFCI built in. The wall plug 30 amp was installed in about 2006.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: "Chargers" (EVSEs) are already GFCIs, so if hardwired they don't need GFCI protection.  However under NEC 2017, **sockets** installed for EV charging need GFCI, see 625.54 and TIA 17-2.  NEC 2020 expands this to all sockets anywhere an EV might charge, see 210.8(A).

Also, beware - cheap sockets melt, they recommend industrial grade ones.

---

If the date on the permit (for installing the socket) was *before* your state adopted NEC 2020, then you don't need to add GFCI to an existing socket.  If it was permitted under NEC 2020 then check your state amendments to see if they deleted the GFCI requirement.

The mobile charge connector contains a "smart GFCI" which will fully protect you from being shocked by your car.  It will not protect you if you mess up while plugging in that huge plug.

The "smart GFCI" will also auto-reset several times, since ground faults are often transient, and often clear on their own later - that way your charging still succeeds.   If the circuit also had a regular/dumb GFCI, that GFCI would trip and charging would just fail.

Note that the charger and its dongle plug *tell the car how much power is safe to take from this socket* - so don't fool around with cheater adapters to make the plug go into sockets it's not designed for.  For instance if you cheat a 50A RV plug into a 30A dryer outlet, it will try to pull 40A - visible in the road trip video I'm about to link.

### The mobile charge connector is for travel

It belongs in your trunk. They gave you 2 sockets: one for level 1 charging and the other for emergency charging at RV parks, [like this guy did](https://youtu.be/_naDg-guomA?t=1573)*.  There are several problems with using a travel unit as your daily unit.

First, they only *come with* 15A/120V and 50A/240V plugs. **That encourages people to dumbly install 50A circuits, when very likely their house cannot handle that** and that can set your panel on fire. The procedure for "figuring out what your house can handle" is called a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation.  You often find 240V/20A (100-130 miles per 10 hours) is achievable but 240V/50A is not. Many travel units sell [alternative dongles](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/265219/47125) for 240V @ 15, 20 or 30 amps.  So that is one way to get your travel unit to work as your daily charge kit.  I'd still want it in my trunk, though.

### For the cost of the socket+GFCI, might as well get a wall unit.

Second, if you're in a state which requires GFCI on 240V ***sockets***, you are looking at a very costly GFCI breaker and also a [very costly socket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKFGW2LfMEg) (because cheap-o range receptacles are *not* designed for continuous 40A all night).  **Very quickly, we're nearly at the cost of a much nicer Wall Unit.** The wall unit avoids both the GFCI and receptacle by being hard-wired.  (note the guy in the video is right about cheap sockets, but is foolish to hook up that wall unit via cord-and-plug; hardwire and the socket *goes away*).

Some people say "But I need to plug-connect my wall unit so I can exchange it easily" but you're already hard-wiring when you hard-wire in **the socket**; and you saw how fast that goes. It's not hard.

And I'll point this out. The perfectly reasonably priced <del>Emporia</del> ** Wallbox Pulsar Plus wall unit has another neat trick that **solves** the "overloading my panel" problem from up top.  You can also buy the <del>Emporia VUE home energy monitor</del> ** [Wallbox energy monitor](https://wallbox.com/en_us/power-meter-for-energy-management-solutions), and it can be set up to coordinate, and adjust EV charging **to avoid overloading the house**.  EV charging is capable of doing that.  Thus you can have 48A charge rate (60A breaker) (that's 150% the speed of the travel unit, by the way) on *literally any house*. Even one with a 60A *service*.

Doesn't the hardwired wall unit need GFCI?  Nope, remember *it already is* a smart GFCI. It really is a GFCI receptacle, just ... with a cord.

---

---

* This was back before the state of Nevada covered US-50 and other desolate routes with DC fast charger stations.

** But the Emporia unit *cannot* do that, because of a design blunder they made [which forecloses its use for energy management](https://www.reddit.com/r/evcharging/comments/11jphw1/comment/jci3ecl/).  The VUE and EVSE don't talk to each other; they communicate only via *"the cloud"*, and if that goes down the EVSE goes to full power. Their rationale is the product is intended for managing your electric invoice (e.g. conforming with peak tariffs), not doing safety-rated energy management.  **The Wallbox and Elmac units (or Myenergi Zappi in Europe) can, however**.

Comment: You’re my hero. What a fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code requires garage and/or outside receptacles to be GFCI protected, in most places.

It is why it is recommended to hardwire EV chargers, since they already have better GFCI protection built in.  Hard wiring bypasses the need for GFCI breaker so far.

If your charger is plug in only, then you probably will need a GFCI breaker for that receptacle.

Comment: Did you read my question

Comment: This is existing wall plug without GFCI

Comment: Is the build in GFCI going to protect the after the plug where it matters

Comment: @Magaman  If the receptacle was installed before code changed, then it is grandfather in and does not require GFCI protection.  If it was installed after GFCI protection was required by code, then it is not in code and should be updated.